How many retractions can a projective surface have to a curve?
Let $X$ be a projective surface (i.e. projective variety over a field, of dimension 2).
How many retractions $\rho : X \to C$ can one have from $X$ to some curve $C$ on $X$? (by retraction I mean the restriction of $\rho$ to $C$ is the identity.)
Is it reasonable to expect only a finite number of such $\rho$? Or do there exist examples where $X$ admits infinitely many such $\rho$ (to infinitely many $C$)?

To clarify: are you fixing the variety $X$ and the curve $C$, and asking how many retractions there are onto $C$? Or asking, for a fixed $X$, about retractions onto some curve $C \subset X$?

@LazzaroCampeotti It is the second situation. I will try to edit the question to make it more clear.

Well, if you have a product of two projective curves, $X=Y\times Z$, then for every graph $C$ of a morphism $Y\to Z$ you have a retraction $X\to C$. Can you now construct an example with infinitely many graphs? Maybe you want to add the "general type" assumption?

@MoisheKohan Thank you for your comment. "for every graph $C$ of a morphism $Y \to Z$ you have a retraction $X \to C$." (1) Will any graph of $Y \to Z$ be isomorphic to $Y$? (2) Is the retraction $X \to C$ not the projection to $Y$?

(1) yes, (2) no. Do you want curves $C$ to be pairwise nonisomorphic (rather than different)?

@MoisheKohan It is not clear to me what the retractions $X \to C$ are exactly. (And yes, ideally, I am hoping for infinitely many curves $C$ with different genera.)

Just think about it for 10 minutes: What maps $X\to Y$ can you think of? How about isomorphisms $Y\to C$? Can you combine these?

@MoisheKohan Thank you! If you would like to submit your comments as an answer, I will gladly accept it!

Here are some examples: Let $Y, Z$ be nonsingular complex projective curves with $Y$ having infinite automorphism group (i.e. genus 0 or 1). Hence, there are infinitely many nonconstant morphisms $f: Y\to Z$. Let $C=G_f$ denote the graph of such a morphism. Then the map
$$
(y,z)\mapsto (y, f(z))
$$
is a retraction $X=Y\times Z\to C$.
On the other hand, for every projective surface $X$, there are only finitely many (up to an isomorphism) pairs $(C, h)$, where $C$ is a nonsingilar curve of genus $\ge 2$ and $h$ is a nonconstant morphism $X\to C$.
I suspect that if you assume that $X$ is a projective surface of general type, then there are only finitely many curves $C\subset X$ which are retracts of $X$.

Thank you for your answer. Could you share why you have a feeling that the last assertion ought to hold? Also, could you provide a reference for the assertion "for every projective surface $X$, there are only finitely many (up to an isomorphism) pairs ..."?

@mathfan24: I do not have a reference but this is an application of Ceveri's finiteness theorem.

@mathfan24: I meant Severi.

No worries, this is how I read it the first time!
